# How do I test a custom hook that has async code?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

The below is a simple custom hook that fetches data from a GET request and returns it.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const useData = (url) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(url)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setData(data));
  }, [url]);

  return [data];
};
```

I am trying to test this custom hook but while testing the actual response I get is an array with a null element `[null]`.

This is my test file.

```
import { renderHook, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useData } from "./useData";

test("fetching the jsonarray", async () => {

  const { result } = renderHook(() =>
    useData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=1")
  );

  let actualResponse;

  await waitFor(() => {
    actualResponse = result.current;
  });

  expect(actualResponse).toEqual([
    {
      userId: 1,
      id: 1,
      title: "delectus aut autem",
      completed: false,
    },
  ]);
});
```

I get the below. As you can see below, in my test case, the actual response is `[null]`. How do I make the the test case wait until the async fetch call is completed?

```
 Expected  - 6
    + Received  + 1

      Array [
    -   Object {
    -     "completed": false,
    -     "id": 1,
    -     "title": "delectus aut autem",
    -     "userId": 1,
    -   },
    +   null,
      ]
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use waitForNextUpdate to wait for the useEffect to run after the initial render:
const { result, waitForNextUpdate } = renderHook(() =>
    useData("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=1")
  );

  await waitForNextUpdate();

await act(async () => {
    await waitFor(() => {
      actualResponse = result.current;
    });
  });

Comment: `waitForNextUpdate` is not available in React Testing Library anymore. They are suggesting that waitFor is sufficient, but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`waitFor`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#waitfor) function works as expected. You should use `result.current[0]`, not `result.current` in the callback of the `waitFor` function since you return the data as `[data]`.

`result.current` is an array `[]`, which is a truthy value, the `waitFor` function will not retry to call the callback.

> Returning a falsy condition is not sufficient to trigger a retry, the callback must throw an error in order to retry the condition

That's why we should use `expect(result.current[0]).toBeTruthy()`, this assertion may throw an error to trigger a retry when `result.current[0]` is `null`.

The `title` of the todo data may be random, that's why I use `expect.any(String)`.

```
import { renderHook, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { useData } from './useData';

test('fetching the jsonarray', async () => {
  const { result } = renderHook(() => useData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=1'));

  await waitFor(() => expect(result.current[0]).toBeTruthy());

  expect(result.current[0]).toEqual(
    expect.arrayContaining([
      expect.objectContaining({
        userId: 1,
        id: 1,
        title: expect.any(String),
        completed: false,
      }),
    ]),
  );
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/77863992/useData.test.ts
  √ fetching the jsonarray (957 ms)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.829 s, estimated 2 s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.
```

package versions:

```json
"@testing-library/react": "^14.1.2",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"jest": "^29.7.0",
```

`jest.setup.js`:

```js
import 'whatwg-fetch';
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
};
```